# bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I just shifted from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)...and following [a tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners) to learn bash scripting...

I wrote a simple shell script

```
#!bin/bash 

echo "Hello World"
```

but when I tried to run it using

```
$ ./test1.sh
```

it throws an error

```
bash: ./test1.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I am running it using

```
$ bash test1.sh
```

it runs fine

I tried searching it and found many answers but all covers errors due to some difference between windows newline `^M` and ubuntu newline...I tried opening it in VIM under binary mode(don't know what it is) but it did'not have any `^M` tag after bin/bash.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You’re missing a leading slash making the shebang an absolute path:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ↑ here
```

In your case, the shell seems to be searching for `./bin/bash`.

The shebang (and also executable permission) is only taken into account if you’re running the script as a program:

```
$ ./test1.sh
```

It is ignored if you directly run the interpreter and provide your script as an argument:

```
$ bash test1.sh
```

See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/850387/250300

Comment: thanks now it is running fine...but can you explain if the script was wrong why it was running using '$ bash test1.sh'?

Comment: @ShubhamPandey Updated, please check now.

Comment: Thanks!  Glad I found your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Although this is an old question, since there is no explanation towards the *^M* problem, maybe it's useful:

- *^M* comes from the difference between "Windows" return and Linux return.
- Simplest solution is to use an editor to convert all the return in your script from CRLF (Win) to LF (Linux), e.g. VS Code.

Comment: probably easier to use `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//'` to fix ^M

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving old topic but I had the same issue and managed to fix it, not sure what exactly helped but did all the things listed below. First of all install Gedit through the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Then make sure that you saved the script with Unix/Linux line ending. After this, type in terminal, while being in the proper folder:

```
chmod +x filename
```

The last thing is replacing in script itself

```
#!bin/bash
```

with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Similar answer already exists. It's a duplicate answer.