# Bash Scripting problem

Tags: bash, scripts

Hello I am lost sorry I dont know why my script wont run

my script is: echo "hi"

**when i type:** sudo ./my.sh

**it shows:** unable to excute my.sh: no such file or directory
hangup

**and when i type:** ./my.sh

**it shows:**  -bash: ./my.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: no such file or directory

it would be great if you can help me thank you very much

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; and your script doesn't have a *shebang* that tells the system what type of script it is, and what interpreter/shell to use to execute it with.  Did you make it executable?

Comment: It looks like your script is **not** just `echo "hi"`, but has a `#!` line - which is incorrectly written with a relative path `#!bin/bash` instead of absolute path `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158577/bin-bash-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. Why the sudo?  At this point, you do not want to run your script as root.
2. All your scripts need to start with the interpreter on the first line  It's the comment sign followed by an exclamation sign.  (The "[Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))")  For bash, your script would look like this:

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `echo "hi"`
3. You should make your scripts executable with `chmod 700 myscript.sh`.  Only then can you execute them like this `./myscript.sh`

On a related note, this is not specifically a Ubuntu question, but a generic scripting question.

Comment: i did use Shebang sorry i didnt not mention. In addition i also gave the right permissions.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Can you execute `whereis bash`?

Comment: Using `chmod +x` instead of `chmod 700` wouldn't affect read and write as well as group/other permissions

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/bash $HOME/my.sh`

Try this and see the difference, you probably are not in the right directory to execute a file. `cd` or `pwd` and `ls` to make sure what you are doing.